# Rapid subsetting of a rast brick

Tags: r, crop, raster, terra

I have a list of polygons that I want to use to subset a `terra::rast` brick with. To do this, I use `terra::crop` together with `lapply`, as show below, and it's fairly slow. Is there a vectorised way of subsetting with polygons rather than `lapply`ing through the polygons?

## Example

First, I load the libraries and create a `rast` object.

```
# Load library                                                                         
library(terra)                                                                         
library(geohashTools)                                                                  
                                                                                       
# Create raster                                                                        
r <- rast(matrix(runif(360 * 2 * 180 *2), ncol = 360 * 2))                             
                                                                                       
# Set extent                                                                           
ext(r)  <- c(-180, 180, -90, 90)                                                       
                                                                                       
# Examine raster                                                                       
r                                                                                      
## class       : SpatRaster                                                            
## dimensions  : 360, 720, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)                                       
## resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)                                                      
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)                          
## coord. ref. :                                                                       
## source      : memory                                                                
## name        :        lyr.1                                                          
## min value   : 7.853378e-07                                                          
## max value   :    0.9999981
```

Next, I create a brick of these objects.

```
# Create a brick                                                                       
b <- c(r, r, r, r, r)                                                                  
                                                                                       
## class       : SpatRaster                                                            
## dimensions  : 360, 720, 5  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)                                       
## resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)                                                      
## extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)                          
## coord. ref. :                                                                       
## sources     : memory                                                                
##               memory                                                                
##               memory                                                                
##               ... and 2 more source(s)                                              
## names       :        lyr.1,        lyr.1,        lyr.1,        lyr.1,        lyr.1  
## min values  : 7.853378e-07, 7.853378e-07, 7.853378e-07, 7.853378e-07, 7.853378e-07  
## max values  :    0.9999981,    0.9999981,    0.9999981,    0.9999981,    0.9999981
```

Here, I'm just creating a load of spatial polygons.

```
# All possible coordinates                                                             
coords <- expand.grid(-180:180, -90:89)                                                
                                                                                       
# Get all unique geohashes for raster                                                  
geohashes <- unique(gh_encode(coords$Var2, coords$Var1, precision = 4L))               
                                                                                       
# Convert to spatial polygons                                                          
sp <- geohashTools::gh_to_sp(geohashes)
```

Finally, I go through each polygon and use it to crop my brick.

```
# Crop raster using geohash polygon                                                    
b_cropped <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(x) terra::crop(b, sp[x]))
```

### Q: Is there a faster way to do this last step?

Comment: I think that `terra` is the fastest way to read and manipulate raster data in `R`. See comparison here https://tmieno2.github.io/R-as-GIS-for-Economists/extract-speed.html

You can try to replace `lapply` with `future_lapply`, to evaluate it in parallel in the background. See https://www.futureverse.org/